# Yii2, ActiveQuery, Postgresql: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, yii2

I got a query

```php
$query = User::find();
$query->joinWith(['profile']);
$query->andWhere(['not', ['user.id' => $this->searching_user_id]]);
$query->andWhere(new Expression('profile.photo::jsonb ? \'id\''));
```

and get error

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters\n
>   Failed to prepare SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"user\" LEFT JOIN \"profile\" ON \"user\".\"id\" = \"profile\".\"user_id\" WHERE (\"user\".\"status\"=:qp0) AND (NOT (\"user\".\"id\"=:qp1)) AND (profile.photo::jsonb ? 'id')

so, if I run an SQL

```sql
SELECT "user".* FROM "user" LEFT JOIN "profile" ON "user"."id" = "profile"."user_id" 
WHERE ("user"."status"='active') 
  AND (NOT ("user"."id"=1)) 
  AND (profile.photo::jsonb ? 'id')
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: the `sql` query you provided, does it fetch the correct records if run through `mysql` console or `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam if you are asking - yes

Answer (score 0):

I I can't test this, as I don't run `postgre sql`, but it looks like the last statement is not quite correct. I think that the table name and field needs to be in parenthesis. You can tell this, because `Yii2` has not properly quoted the field names. Also you have mixed two sets of single-quote brackets, which php often does not like, although you have properly escaped the single quotes.. Try nesting them like this;

```
$query->andWhere(new Expression("(profile).photo::jsonb ? \'id\'"));
```

As I said I can't test this, but hope it is of some use to you

Comment: ummm `yii2` uses `{{%table}}.[[column_name]]` i think and `profile` is a relation

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, but `Expression` is evaluated exactly as you've written it, no relations are expanded.